# re.sub with matched replacement

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Python and re.sub to replace strings by a previously matched string. Basic exemple :

From this :

```
Cat_A
 SomeStuff
Cat_B
 SomeStuff
Cat_C
 SomeStuff
```

To this :

```
Cat_A
 Cat_A
Cat_B
 Cat_A
Cat_C
 Cat_A
```

But when I try to use re.sub for this, I'm having some kind of operand error.

Thanks !

Edit :

Ok so my question is really not precise so here is an example based on what I really what to achieve.
I have an output like this :

```
6500_1#show ip arp vrf A

Protocol  Address          Age (min)
Internet  1.1.1.1                 - 
Internet  1.1.1.2                 0 
Internet  1.1.1.3                 0 
Internet  1.1.1.4             - 

6500_1#show ip arp vrf B    
Protocol  Address          Age (min)
Internet  2.2.2.1                 0 
Internet  2.2.2.2                  -
```

I want to replace "Internet" word by the previous vrf name to get something like this :

```
6500_1#show ip arp vrf A
Protocol  Address          Age (min)    
vrf A  1.1.1.1                -     
vrf A  1.1.1.2                0     
vrf A  1.1.1.3                0     
vrf A  1.1.1.4                -     
6500_1#show ip arp vrf B    
Protocol  Address          Age (min)    
vrf B  2.2.2.1                0     
vrf B  2.2.2.2                 -
```

I'm tying to use re.sub for this but I'm not able to push a regex for the replacement part.

Comment: What did you try and what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Please provide some real world examples. As your question stands now, you may be able to simply split.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you made a typo in the question text and answering according your question title this will work:

```
import re

s = '''Cat_A
 SomeStuff
Cat_B
 SomeStuff
Cat_C
 SomeStuff'''

s = re.sub(r'(Cat_\w)\s*(\w*)', r'\1\n \1', s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an error and trashed your edit on the original post. Please redo it if you like.